# Ridge Regression Coefficient Estimate is linear

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I was able to derive the formula for the Ridge Regression Coefficient Estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{ridge}$. However, I am not 100% sure what it means in terms of showing that the **Ridge Regression Coefficient Estimate** is linear in **Y**, but my intuition is that if I expand the following term by using SVD method on matrix X which has centered columns (leading to a symmetric matrix X):
$$
(\textbf{X}^{T}\textbf{X}+\lambda\textbf{I})^{-1}\textbf{X}^{T} = \textbf{V}(\textbf{D}^{2}+\lambda \textbf{I})^{-1}\textbf{V}^{T}\textbf{VD}\textbf{U}^{T}
$$the resulting result will have a linear form like $a+bx$.

Am I correct?

If not, please give me some tips.

Comment: Linear in $\mathbf{y}$ should just mean that the ridge regression coefficient estimate is "a matrix times $\mathbf{y}$". Were you allowed to assume the formula for the ridge regression coefficient estimate in this problem, or you had to derive it?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I was able to derive the formula for the Ridge Regression Coefficient Estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{ridge}$. So based on your response, all I need to prove is that the terms multiplying by **y** is a matrix, not a scalar. Am I right?

Comment: $\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{y}}$Even a scalar would be fine, since this would give a matrix too (i.e. $c\y = cI\y$, where $I$ is an identity matrix). The problem basically requires you to show that $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{ridge}$ is of the form $M\y$ for some matrix $M$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Would you be able to post a response to my question so I can accept your response and close the post appropriately please? Thank you.

Comment: It is linear:
$$
\hat{\beta}^{\text{ridge}}(\lambda)=\left[(\textbf{X}^{\top}\textbf{X}+\lambda\textbf{I})^{-1}\textbf{X}^{\top}\right] \times \textbf{Y}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{y}}$The problem requires you to show that $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{ridge}$ is of the form $M\y$ for some matrix $M$.